# My pop method is not working

Tags: javascript

hey guys i am a newbie to core javascript.
i am learning to make an array. I wrote this code but somehow the `pop` is not working.

```
 var players=['david','micky','Ryan','Benjamin','fransesco'];
   var totalPlayers=players.length;
   var lastPlayer=players.pop();
   alert=("The Last Player is " + lastPlayer);
   alert("The total number of players are " + totalPlayers);
```

Now, the `lastplayer` alert is not showing up.
Please tell me where i am doing it wrong.thanks.

Comment: Check your browser's console, there should be an error.

Comment: For future reference, simply opening your browser's developer tools would have displayed an error and told you exactly what line of code caused it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a syntax error here:

```
alert="The Last Player is " + lastPlayer);
```

try this instead , it will work

```
alert("The Last Player is " + lastPlayer);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: var players=['david','micky','Ryan','Benjamin','fransesco'];lastPlayer= players.pop();alert("The Last Player is " + lastPlayer);

Comment: just tried in console worked for me @designerNProgrammer

Comment: @designerNProgrammer your syntax of alert was wrong , you were trying alert=" instead you had to write alert(", .Hope this answers your question.If it helped please accept the answer.thanks

Comment: Yes got it. Thanks. it was actually alert= that was giving the probblem. Thanks.

Comment: please upvote me as i dont think this question deserved downvote.thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the 3 line
alert="The Last Player is " + lastPlayer);
it should be

```
alert ( "The Last Player is " + lastPlayer);
```

Answer (score 0):

make your array `var players=['david','micky','Ryan','Benjamin','fransesco'];` global and remove = after alert

```
alert=("The Last Player is " + lastPlayer);

alert("The Last Player is " + lastPlayer);
```